# Log request body in quarkus-resteasy-reactive

Tags: quarkus

I want to log the request body in a server response filter method. I tried this:

```
@ServerResponseFilter
public Uni<Void> filter(ContainerRequestContext request, ContainerResponseContext response) {
    logger.info(((QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext) request).getRequestEntity());
    return Uni.createFrom().nullItem();
}
```

But it didn't work because of:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.server.runtime.filters.PreventAbortResteasyReactiveContainerRequestContext cannot be cast to class io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.server.runtime.QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext (io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.server.runtime.filters.PreventAbortResteasyReactiveContainerRequestContext and io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.server.runtime.QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext are in unnamed module of loader io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader @ae13544)
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported by the framework yet. The request is here https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/17280

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should really be checking if the request body is of type JSON XML or any human readable format before logging to the console. You don't want to find out your logs are 16gb in size of unicode characters from image uploads.

Here is what I think you may be looking for (untested so may need some fixing).

```
@ServerResponseFilter
public Uni<Void> filter(ContainerRequestContext request, ContainerResponseContext response) {
    logger.info(new String(request.getEntityStream​().readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    return Uni.createFrom().nullItem();
}
```

Comment: Yes, I am doing all the checks, I didn't put here so the code is more focused on the problem. This does not work, the input stream is already read at this point. Read all bytes would just return zero.